# Looping in Vue and adding dynamic className

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, v-for

I am quite new to Vue and I have an issue.
I have an array of objects and I want the wrapper of the loop to have dynamic className
For example

```
<div v-for="({time, date, name}, i) in myObject" :key="i" class="my-custom-class">
```

well, if the key (i) is greater than 3 then I want the className to have a different name
or at least to add an extra name (like hiddenDiv).

I know is not possible to add the v-if condition in the v-for statement.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can dynamically bind class like :class="{ 'red-button': name === 'error' }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this using computed property...

```
<div v-for="({time, date, name}, i) in myObject"
:key="i" :class="getClassName(i)" class="my-custom-class" >
```

and in your computed

```
computed: {

 getClassName() {
  return i => {
     if(i === 0) return 'classOne';
     elseif(i === 1) return 'classTwo'
     else return 'classThree';
    // In this way you can maintain as many classNames you want based on the condition
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could bind the class using a condition based on the current loop index `:class="{'hide-div':i>3}"`:

```
<div v-for="({time, date, name}, i) in myObject"
:key="i" :class="{'hide-div':i>3}" class="my-custom-class" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a dynamic class in vue then you can use class bindings to apply a specific class to the element.

You can read about class and style bindings [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

Also, you can define a method with the class and apply some conditions on which the class needs to be changed.